Converting Plink .bed files to .bcf *with* an AC (allele count) field?
I have some extremely large (N ~ 400,000) Plink .bed files that I want to phase using shapeit5.
Shapeit5 requires input data be in .bcf or .vcf format, and that it have an "AC" (allele count) field.
Here is what I have managed to figure out:

I can convert the files to .bcf easily enough with Plink2's --export bcf option, but the resulting .bcf file has no "AC" field.
I can add an "AC" field with bcftools +fill-AN-AC or bcftools +fill-tags -t AN,AC which outputs a new file with that field added, but this is extremely slow (several hours) because bcftools only uses one thread to calculate the allele counts (the --threads flag is for output compression only, it does not affect these commands)
I can split the chromosome into several chunks, use bcftools to add an "AC" field to each chunk, and then use bcftools concat to combine the chunks back into one big .bcf file. This is much faster, but also undesirable because of the amount of storage space used (requires temporarily making 3 copies of a very large dataset)

Is there a tool that will let me go from Plink .bed to .bcf while adding an "AC" field all in one step? Or if not, is there at least a better option for adding an "AC" field to the large .bcf file that will run with multiple threads and not require me to manually split the data into chunks?
